# style-position is set to absolute value of the input tag. kendo-ui datepicker object during the rendering process

Tags: input, datepicker, position, kendo-ui, absolute

style-position is set to absolute value of the input html tag. datepicker problem occurs during rendering. datepicker after rendering, have adjusted the input object as static style-position value, the problem was resolved.

caused by reason?

```
<input id="datepicker" style="left:40px; top:40px; height:27px; width:100px; position:absolute">
```

example:http://jsfiddle.net/kTLUn/

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to overcome this by placing the date picker in a wrapping div and positioning the wrapper as absolute. I guess based on the CSS of the kendo datepicker you can't directly make it absolutely positioned...

```
<div style="left:40px; top:40px; height:27px; width:100px; position:absolute">
   <input id="datepicker" />
</div>
```